# JFreeChart - RangeAxis autorange and don't start from 0

Tags: java, jfreechart

In JFreeChart how can I ask the RangeAxis to be automatically 'optimize' itself?

Right now I have bunch of data to be displayed between 25.00 and 27.00, but the range always starts from 0 which does not look nice:

[image]

I've tried to set *plot.getRangeAxis().setAutoRange(true)*, but it does not work. Of course I can calculate my min and max values then later I can set it with *setRange(min, max)*, but is there any bundled function to do this?

Repro:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

public class LineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame {

    public LineChart_AWT( String applicationTitle , String chartTitle ) {
          super(applicationTitle);
          JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
             chartTitle,
             "Dates","Temperature",
             createDataset(),
             PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
             true,true,false);

          CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) lineChart.getPlot();
          //plot.getRangeAxis().setRange(25, 27);
          //plot.getRangeAxis().setAutoRange(true);

          ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( lineChart );
          chartPanel.setPreferredSize( new java.awt.Dimension( 560 , 367 ) );
          setContentPane( chartPanel );
       }

       private DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset( ) {
          DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );

          dataset.addValue( 26.44,"Temperature","2019-08-18 00:00");
          dataset.addValue( 26.2,"Temperature","2019-08-18 01:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.93,"Temperature","2019-08-18 02:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.71,"Temperature","2019-08-18 03:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.54,"Temperature","2019-08-18 04:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.42,"Temperature","2019-08-18 05:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.25,"Temperature","2019-08-18 06:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.19,"Temperature","2019-08-18 07:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.25,"Temperature","2019-08-18 08:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.36,"Temperature","2019-08-18 09:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.52,"Temperature","2019-08-18 10:00");
          dataset.addValue( 25.86,"Temperature","2019-08-18 11:00");
          dataset.addValue( 26.51,"Temperature","2019-08-18 12:00");
          dataset.addValue( 26.82,"Temperature","2019-08-18 13:00");


          return dataset;
       }

       public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
          LineChart_AWT chart = new LineChart_AWT(
             "X-axis demo" ,
             "Y-range is wrong");

          chart.pack( );
          RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );
          chart.setVisible( true );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work when you use [`setLowerMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setLowerMargin-double-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, it must be specified with [`NumberAxis#setAutoRangeIncludesZero`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setAutoRangeIncludesZero-boolean-) whether the zero-value should be contained in the displayed interval:

```
plot.getRangeAxis().setAutoRange(true);                            // uncomment
((NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis()).setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false); // add
```

Results in:

[image]